# Proxy with authenticaiton in headless Chrome selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to run multiple selenium chromes, all with different proxies. I want to run in headless because of performance.
I have tried 3 different libraries for proxy. They worked, but only in non headless, because headless doesn't support chrome extensions.
I also tried "--proxy-server=user:pass@proxyurl" in arguments. Didn't work either.

Is there any other way to run selenium with proxy. Without creating local proxy (because I need multiple) and without chrome extensions? Thank you very much for all answers

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of struggle I found solution
This piece of code helped me

options.AddArguments(new List() { "no-sandbox", "disable-web-security", "ignore-certificate-errors", "headless", "--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false" });

```
        string username = string.Empty;
        string password = string.Empty;
        //proxy
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy))
        {
            //ip, port, username, passwords
            string[] proxySplit = proxy.Split(":");

            Proxy p = new Proxy();
            p.SslProxy = proxySplit[0] + ":" + proxySplit[1];
            p.HttpProxy = proxySplit[0] + ":" + proxySplit[1]; 
            p.FtpProxy = proxySplit[0] + ":" + proxySplit[1];                
            options.Proxy = p;

            username = proxySplit[2];
            password = proxySplit[3];
        }

        driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

        var handler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler()
        {
            UriMatcher = _ => true,
            Credentials = new PasswordCredentials(username, password)
        };
        driver.Manage().Network.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);
```